# Why doesn't [FromQuery] work when unit testing a Razor page?

Tags: asp.net-core, moq, request.querystring

I have this property in a PageModel:

`[FromQuery(Name = "paypalPlanId")] public string? paypalPlanId { get; set; }`

It works when calling the page within the application - the property is set to the value of the querystring parameter.

When I call it from a unit test using a mocked HttpContext, with a mocked HttpRequest containing the the same  querystring, it does not work - the property is null.

[image: This shows the correct value when running the app]

[image: This shows it is null when running the test]

Here is the calling part of the unit test:

```
// arrange
queryParameters.Add(Tuple.Create("paypalPlanId", "TESTPLAN1"));
var config = CoachWorkbench.Test.TestHelpers.TestHelperConfiguration.GetConfiguration();
HttpContext httpContext = CommonTestHttpContext();
PlanEditModel page = new PlanEditModel(config);
page.AddPageModelContextExtension(httpContext, errorList);

// Act
IActionResult result = await page.OnGetAsync();
```

I have hundreds of other unit tests using the same mocked HttpContext & HttpRequest code and they work fine.  Testing specifically for the correct QueryString also works fine.  I was expecting the [FromQuery] field to be populated with the query value.

I am assuming that either a) the [FromQuery] functionality uses some HttpRequest component that I am unaware of and have not mocked or b) the [FromQuery] functionality uses some middleware functionality that I am unaware of and that is bypassed by the unit test.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: From my understanding, this is a unit test, not an integration test and you are not sending any requests at all. You create PlanEditModel for yourself.  Why you do not set up the PaypalPlanId property directly on the line where you are creating PlanEditModel? From my perspective, this test should not know anything about how and when HttpContext populate the parameters

Comment: This is a simple solution to this problem as a unit test - thanks for providing it.  This tells me  that there is no separation between my unit testing and integration testing and so I got the title of this question wrong (I am trying to simulate an actual call to the page). I will read up on separating these two test types better.  I am still not sure why [FromQuery] does not work here though.